# Django named URL parameters no longer working after upgrade to 1.10 or 1.11

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I have an old Django app which uses the URL template tag this way:

```
{% url 'smart_service.views.view_name' %}
```

So far it worked greatly, but after the update to version 1.10 nothing works anymore and any use made that way returns `NoReverseMatch`.

I can solve this problem by putting `app_name = 'smart_service'` into my `urls.py` file and by changing the url tag to this:

```
{% url 'smart_service:view_name' %}
```

This is a tedious task and very prone to errors, I'd like to avoid it unless strictly necessary.

Is the first use-case been deprecated? If not, why isn't it working anymore? Are there specific advantages in using one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't avoid this change when you upgrade to Django 1.10+.

Support for reversing urls using the dotted Python path was [deprecated in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.8/#passing-a-dotted-path-to-reverse-and-url) and [removed in 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-10).

You must change your `{% url %}` tags to use the view name, e.g.

```
{% url 'view_name' %}
```

If you add a namespace to your `urls.py`, for example `app_name = 'smart_service'`, then you must include the namespace in the `{% url %}` tag.

```
{% url 'smart_service:view_name' %}
```